# Cannot GET error for Express routing with parameters :

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, lodash, ejs

I'm getting a Cannot GET error when I try express routing with parameters for the first time and I don't know why.

It worked fine and I installed lodash and now nothing works anymore.

Here`s the code:

```
    app.get("/posts/:postName"), function (req, res) {

  let requestedTitle = req.params.postName;

    posts.forEach(function(post) {

      let storedTitle = post.title;

      if (storedTitle === requestedTitle) {
        console.log('match found');
      } else {
        console.log('no match found');
      }
    });
  };
```

I'm using Localhost and when I try to run it it gives me a Cannot Get error.

For example I enter: **http://localhost:3000/posts/test**
And usually it kept me on the home route and console logged if it matched one of my entries before or not.

I have Express installed and everything heres the complete code. But it just won't work anymore after installing lodash, do you guys see an error somewhere here? I'm staring at this for 3 days now lol:

```
    //jshint esversion:6

const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");

const _ = require('lodash');

const homeStartingContent = "text";

const app = express();

let posts = [];



app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));


app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.render(__dirname + "/views/home.ejs", {homeStartingContent: homeStartingContent, posts: posts});





});


app.get('/about', (req, res) => {
    res.render('about', {aboutContent: aboutContent});
   });

   app.get('/contact', (req, res) => {
       res.render('contact', {contactContent: contactContent});
      });

      app.get('/compose', (req, res) => {
          res.render('compose');
         });

 app.post('/compose', (req, res) => {


   posts.push(req.body);

console.log(posts)


res.redirect('/')


});




app.get("/posts/:postName"), function (req, res) {

  let requestedTitle = req.params.postName;

    posts.forEach(function(post) {

      let storedTitle = post.title;

      if (storedTitle === requestedTitle) {
        console.log('match found');
      } else {
        console.log('no match found');
      }
    });
  };










app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

In the Express documentation it showed this code example and I feel my code should definitely work. I don't understand why it is not.

```
    app.get('/users/:userId/books/:bookId', (req, res) => {
  res.send(req.params)
})
```

Comment: Can you please indent your code properly to make it more readable.

Answer (score 2):

Notice the closing parentheses:

```
app.get("/posts/:postName"), function (req, res) {
                          ^
```

It shouldn't be there, but at the end of the handler function.

Comment: That's it! Can't believe i missed this. Thank you Robert